# lxpanel won't save width settings when it's at the left edge

Tags: lubuntu, lxpanel

I'm using `lxpanel` for my panel. This bug might be new because I am facing this issue since 15.10. Here's how you can reproduce the bug:

1. Run `lxpanel`
2. Go to terminal and type in `lxpanelctl config` or go to `Panel Settings`
3. In the `Edge` section click `Left`. You will notice that the `Width` automatically goes to 120 pixels.

I can change it back to 30 pixels every time the computer starts up but it's really annoying. Can anyone solve this?

PS: Here goes the panel config:

```
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.

Global {
  edge=left
  allign=left
  margin=0
  widthtype=percent
  width=30
  height=100
  transparent=0
  tintcolor=#aeaeae
  alpha=255
  setdocktype=1
  setpartialstrut=1
  usefontcolor=1
  fontcolor=#ffffff
  background=0
  backgroundfile=/usr/share/lxpanel/images/lubuntu-background.png
  iconsize=30
  usefontsize=1
  fontsize=15
  align=left
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=4
  }
  expand=0
}
Plugin {
  type=menu
  Config {
    image=/home/diamond/Downloads/white-circle-md.png
    system {
    }
    separator {
    }
    item {
      command=run
    }
    separator {
    }
    item {
      image=gnome-logout
      command=logout
    }
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=4
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=4
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=taskbar
  expand=1
  Config {
    tooltips=1
    IconsOnly=0
    AcceptSkipPager=1
    ShowIconified=1
    ShowMapped=1
    ShowAllDesks=0
    UseMouseWheel=1
    UseUrgencyHint=1
    FlatButton=0
    MaxTaskWidth=30
    spacing=1
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=tray
  Config {
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=3
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=wincmd
  Config {
    Button1=iconify
    Button2=shade
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=volumealsa
  Config {
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=4
  }
  expand=0
}
Plugin {
  type=dclock
  Config {
    ClockFmt=%H %M
    TooltipFmt=%A %x
    BoldFont=0
    IconOnly=0
    CenterText=0
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=launchbar
  Config {
    Button {
      id=/usr/share/applications/lubuntu-logout.desktop
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh and one more thing, the width in the config file doesn't work when the `Edge` is `Left`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug and I hope they will adjust it in the next versions. Meanwhile, you can install the 0.7.2-1 version that has not this bug and it is quite the same of 0.8.1 (at least by the graphical point of view)

You can download the .deb package for installation here:
i386: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/i386/lxpanel/download
amd64: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/lxpanel/download
lxpanel-data: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/lxpanel-data/download

Before you install the packages, you must remove the current version:

```
sudo apt-get remove lxpanel-data lxpanel
```

then you can install lxpanel-data and then lxpanel.

To avoid system auto-update to 0.8.1 you can launch

```
sudo apt-mark hold lxpanel
sudo apt-mark hold lxpanel-data
```